# How to store the filename of an Icon as a String?

Tags: java, icons

So let's say I have some Icon:

```
    Icon something = new ImageIcon("somefile.png");
```

And I want to store that `somefile.png` in some Strings. How do I do that?

Obviously I can not do `Icon.toString()` or cast so I am kind of stumped by what I am sure it has a simple solution.

Thanks!

Comment: So, I'm assuming you didn't create the icon yourself, so you can't just do `String s = "somefile.png";` before creating the icon?

Comment: @azurefrog No, unfortunately that would over-complicate things because the icons are placed on JButtons that are swap them around when clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you see here : http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/ImageIcon.java

The filename goes directly to the `description`-Field what is used in the `toString()`. Try

```
String filename = something + "";
```

What indirectly calls the `.toString()`.

Comment: Thanks so much! Didn't even think of that!

Comment: @azurefrog `getDescription()` is allowed for `ImageIcon` but not allowed for `Icon` and he said he can not cast.

Comment: If the Icon is not guaranteed to be an ImageIcon, its toString method can not be replied upon.

Comment: @VGR You are right, but for the case in the question it is. For real? I think azurefrog is right, the `toString()` is much better than ` + ""`.

Comment: Ah, I missed the "cannot cast" bit.  You're right, `getDescription()` isn't available on `Icon`, so you have no choice to to rely on `toString()` here.

Comment: @azurefrog Hey, the *I can not cast* and the *I can not call toString* makes me wondering why he *can not* do so. I think you are reading the intelligent way and ignore the "i can not call toString" :D